# TYPO3 realurl removes GET values

Tags: typo3, realurl

I need help =/
I updated TYPO3 to 4.5.5 and an older Version of realurl.

The plugin we're using gets the GET parameters by reading the 't3lib_div::_GET();' variable.. realurl does not let through values that are submited by the original GET method, it only passes the "readable" url parameters....

so:
www.anypage.com/welcome/any
works with config:

```
array(
 'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin_pi1[database]',
 'valueMap' => array(
      'one' => 'one',
      'any' => 'any'
  ),
  'noMatch' => 'bypass'
)
```

but:
www.anypage.com/welcome/?database=any

does not pass the value ('any') to the plugin...

Comment: Did any of the answers help, or does your problem persist?

Answer (score 2):

I second Koopa's answer.

In addition to that the variable must include the prefix:

```
www.anypage.com/welcome/?tx_plugin_pi1[database]=any
```

or you update the real url config to:

```
array(
 'GETvar' => 'database',
 'valueMap' => array(
      'one' => 'one',
      'any' => 'any'
  ),
  'noMatch' => 'bypass'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable should always be accessible through $this->piVars['database'], is it not?